# Call any method in mainPage when periodicTask start WP7-8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, scheduled-tasks, background-process, tiles

Hi I use this tutorial: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Working_with_Live_Tiles_in_Windows_Phone_7

Now my problem, When periodic task run/end I need call method which is in mainPage. This method is download some data from server and update page values. Does anyone know how I can call this method depend on task or how call method in ScheduledTaskAgent or something similar...

```
 void LoadCountryData() // this method try download data from web 

    {...}
```

Now in short. App will automatically download data from web every 30 minutes and refresh my data so good is I dont need run this app manual and call refresh via button click action.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a Helper class witch does the processing you need and call it from both: 
periodic task or Page

```
public class DataHelper
{
    public static CustomDataObjectType Data;
    public static void LoadCountryData()
    {
         //Data= whatever you do to get data
    }
}
```

Call wherever you need it by simply doing

```
DataHelper.LoadCountryData();
```